# How to wrap dx-data-grid and the it's tools into another component and make it controller?

Tags: angular, devextreme-angular

We are developing an angular application with [devexpress.com](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/Overview/Angular/Light/), and I would like to make 'my-grid' controller with dx-data-grid, I would like to wrap dx-data-grid tools into mine but there was a problem, could you help me to solve it?

> dx-data-grid.component.html

```
<dx-data-grid id="gridContainer"
            [dataSource]="dataSource"
            [showBorders]="true"
            [allowColumnResizing]="true"
            [columnAutoWidth]="true"
            [allowColumnReordering]="true">

    <!-- filter -->
    <dxo-filter-row [visible]="true"></dxo-filter-row>
    <dxo-header-filter [visible]="true"></dxo-header-filter>

    <!-- column chooser -->
    <dxo-column-chooser [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-chooser>

   **<!-- COLUMN WILL APPEAR TO HEAR -->**

    <!-- summary -->
    <dxo-summary>
        <dxi-total-item column="branchId" summaryType="count"></dxi-total-item>

        <dxi-total-item column="docKind" summaryType="sum">
            <!--<dxo-value-format type="decimal" [precision]="2"></dxo-value-format>-->
        </dxi-total-item>
    </dxo-summary>

    <!-- pagination -->
    <dxo-paging [pageSize]="10"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-pager [showPageSizeSelector]="true" [allowedPageSizes]="false" [showInfo]="true">
    </dxo-pager>

</dx-data-grid>
```

> my-grid.component.html

```
<my-grid [dataSource]="dataSource" 
        [showBorders]="true" 
        [allowColumnResizing]="true" 
        [columnAutoWidth]="true"
        [allowColumnReordering]="true">

    <!-- columns -->
    <dxi-column dataField="Product_ID"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Product_Name" [width]="250"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Product_Cost" caption="Cost" dataType="number" format="currency"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Product_Sale_Price" caption="Sale Price" dataType="number" format="currency"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Product_Retail_Price" caption="Retail Price" dataType="number" format="currency"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Product_Current_Inventory" caption="Inventory"></dxi-column>

</my-grid>
```

the dx-data-grid options I can Input but `dxi-clumns` I cannot.

> my-grid.component.ts

```
@Input()
public dataSource: string;

@Input()
public columnAutoWidth: boolean;

@Input()
public allowColumnReordering: boolean;

@Input()
public showBorders: boolean;

@Input()
public allowColumnResizing: boolean;

@ViewChild(DxDataGridComponent) dxDataGrid: DxDataGridComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dxDataGrid.dataSource = this.dataSource;
    this.dxDataGrid.columnAutoWidth = this.columnAutoWidth;
    this.dxDataGrid.allowColumnReordering = this.allowColumnReordering;
    this.dxDataGrid.showBorders = this.showBorders;
    this.dxDataGrid.allowColumnResizing = this.allowColumnResizing;
}
```

**So I need to input `dxi-columns` into my-grid, in another case maybe `dxo-paging` and so on.**
**Thanks you**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my solution.
[my-grid.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e9kdqo0rqhw9rmf/AAD4CtJPNtcz87YI_-bVjwUca?dl=0)

Comment: It's deleted from Dropbox so no help in this answer

Comment: is it okey that I'll ad